# Unable yo load images on Django Website...shows that the image is not found

Tags: html, django

[image][please do check the image. it also consists of the error code and the folder where it shows that the file is not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY3Cd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a folder named media in project folder and save your images at that and in src of write media/imagename try this

Comment: Otherwise kindly explain your problem in detail

Comment: i created a folder names media and stored my imagex there..what about the second step..i Didnt get you??

Comment: can you elaborate the second step

Comment: Yeah I can but first can you show your piece of code where you're getting the error

Comment: In production, you'll just have the HTML generated from your template pointing to wherever the host has media files stored. So your template will just have for example

<img src="../media/foo.png">

Comment: foo.png is image name

Comment: <div class="m-3">
 <h2>UNITED Deals </h2>
 
 <div class="owl-carousel" id="slider1">
 {% for m in mobiles %} 
  <a href="{% url 'product-detail' m.id %}" class="btn"><div class="item"><img src="{{m.product_image.url}}" alt="" height="200px" width="200px"><span class="fw-bold">{{m.title}}</span><br><span class="fs-5">Rs. {{m.discounted_price}}</span></div></a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>

Comment: this the code in which the product_image_url should work perfectly in getting the image

Comment: class Product (models.Model):
    title= models.CharField (max_length=100)
    selling_price = models.FloatField() 
    discounted_price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    brand = models.CharField (max_length=100)
    category= models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    product_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='producting')
    def _str_(self):
        return str(self.id)

Comment: what product_image is doing is given in the above code

Comment: Ok now I get the point that you are uploading an image with models can you show me your view.py?

Comment: class ProductView(View):
    def get(self,request):
        topwears = Product.objects.filter(category='TW')
        bottomwears = Product.objects.filter(category='BW')
        mobiles = Product.objects.filter(category='M')
        return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'topwears' : topwears, 'bottomwears':bottomwears, 'mobiles':mobiles})

Comment: class ProductDetailView(View):
    def get(self,request,pk):
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request,'app/productdetail.html',{'product':product})

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import Customer, Product, Cart, OrderPlaced

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product


def home(request):

    file = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        "files": file
        }
    return render(request, 'book/home.html', context)

Comment: try something like this in view and for template where are you adding image do the following

Comment: {% block content %}
{% for book in files %}
<div class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row border">
            <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="about-box">
                    <figure><img src='{{ book.upload.url }}' alt="img" /></figure>
                </div>
            </div>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}

Comment: book in book.upload.url is your app name

Comment: try this and gave mr feedback

Comment: where to add this code...i didnt understand

Comment: i have wrote it as general block content was for templete and from django.shortcuts.... for view.py

Comment: or rather than this

Comment: edit these lines in your setting.py MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/' with MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'producting')

MEDIA_URL = '/producting/'

Comment: and in url.py file add this

Comment: if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: And if you like the ans and clarification please check my answer correct and give an upvote if you like

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/producting/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'producting')     updated my setting.py

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'  MEDIA_URL = '/producting/' MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'producting')

Comment: Only these 3 required

Comment: And please add this in url.py of project folder

Comment: if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Please try this an tell me

Comment: still the same message

Comment: where to add in urls.py

Comment: from django.urls import path
from app import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.ProductView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('product-detail/<int:pk>', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product-detail'),

Comment: path('cart/', views.add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
    path('buy/', views.buy_now, name='buy-now'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('address/', views.address, name='address'),
    path('orders/', views.orders, name='orders'),
    path('changepassword/', views.change_password, name='changepassword'),
    path('mobile/', views.mobile, name='mobile'),

Comment: path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('registration/', views.customerregistration, name='customerregistration'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
] 
if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: At the end in url.py

Comment: Can share the pic of producting that where it is in project folder

Comment: producting folder is in the same folder as of the main project.

Comment: But still I want to see kindly edit your question and add image of it

Comment: added.please do check

Comment: created another folder producting inside the original one

Comment: actually this happens when you change setting after creating folder and collaborate it with views models and URLs